# How to run and watch local server at the same time?

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, git, npm

I've been having some issues setting up my local server. I can get it to run with `php artisan serve`, but I can't add `npm run watch` at the same time.

I've done `npm install` and updated my node too. It says to run `php artisan serve` first and then to run `npm run watch`, but once I've done the artisan serve, it doesn't let me type in anything else. 
If I run `npm run watch` before `php artisan serve`, it opens up the wrong port (3000 instead of 8000), too.

Can someone please let me know what is going on? Have you encountered this before? Nothing I could find on here matched my problem, but in case I missed it, please let me know. And if you need any further information, as in logs, etc.

Comment: Open a new terminal tab and run `npm run watch` on that one. If you are using default Windows cmd take a loot at [cmder](https://cmder.net/) or the new Windows Terminal.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Never even considered this as an option lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a new terminal tab and run `npm run watch` on that one. If you are using default Windows cmd take a loot at [cmder](https://cmder.net/) or the new Windows Terminal.