# Npm run watch is compiling but I can't load page

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, npm-run

I am using Laravel 8 + Vue.

When I use `php artisan serve` it loads my page on `http://127.0.0.1:8000`. But when I use
`npm run watch` it compiles (I get notification every time I change my code that it compiles successfully) but I can't reach my page.

```
This site can’t be reached
127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

My package.json file:

```
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "jquery": "^3.6",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
        "sass": "^1.32.11",
        "sass-loader": "^11.0.1",
        "vue": "^2.6.12",
        "vue-loader": "^15.9.7",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^4.3.1"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "npm-watch": "^0.11.0",
        "vue-router": "^3.5.2",
        "watch": "^1.0.2"
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying this using two separate terminal windows, or just in one? See if this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57534939/how-to-run-and-watch-local-server-at-the-same-time

Comment: Oooh, I didn't know this was even possible. Thank you very much this helped me.